# Button click not populating trix editor with laravel livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, trix

I have a functionality in my app that allows a user click a button to fetch a random blogpost and then assigns the result to a variable in my livewire component. Now what i want to do is show the result in my trix wysiwyg editor but its not showing. When i use a normal text editor it works fine. Here is my code;

//My Component

```
public $totalBody;


    public $trixId;


    public function mount()
    {
        $this->trixId = 'trix-' . uniqid();
    }

public function getBody()
    {
       /* Makes api call here /*
        $this->totalBody = 'Result from api calll';
    }
```

Then in my view

```
                  <div class="col-12 mt-4">
                                <button class="btn bg-indigo-400 text-white" wire:click="getBody">
                                   
                                    <span wire:loading.remove.delay wire:target="getBody">
                                        Generate Body
                                    </span>
                                    <div wire:loading.delay wire:target="generateArticle">
                                        Generating...
                                    </div>
                                </button>
                            </div>

                 <div class="col-12" wire:ignore>
                            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/trix/1.3.1/trix.min.css" />
                        
                            <input id="{{ $trixId }}" type="hidden" value="{{ $totalBody }}" />
                            <textarea class="form-control" wire:model="totalBody"></textarea>
                            <trix-editor input="{{ $trixId }}"></trix-editor>
                        
                            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/trix/1.3.1/trix.min.js"></script>
                            <script>
                                var trixEditor = document.getElementById("{{ $trixId }}")

                                console.log(trixEditor.editor);

                                addEventListener("trix-change", function(event) {
                                    @this.set('totalBody', trixEditor.getAttribute('value'))
                                })
                            </script>
                        </div>
```

I added the extra for testing and it actually works but the editor does not show the data. When i try to type normally it shows but not the button click.

Answer (score 0):

first be sure your blade component are between 1 tag
forexample they are between div or form
like this

```
  <div>  
   // your component code
 </div>
```

and when you use wire:ignore the wire:model doesnt send data from blade to component
you can use wire:ignore.self
or you can use wire:ignore and set event and send data from js like this

```
   $('#due_date').on('change', function (e) {
                       let data = $(this).val();
                   
                   @this.set('invoice.due_date', data);
                   });
```